# Integromat and google verification

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

Good afternoon! I want to confirm the integromat app in the Google app to upload my own files to Google Drive. Moved to the moderation stage, but the message "Comply with domain verification requirements"appears. Tell me, how did you solve the problem of checking the application in the google cloud app and the integrator service in order not to reauthorize the application every 7 days?

Comment: Related Stack Overlfow question about `integromat.com` domain verification: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73183563/integromat-make-google-verification-for-gmail-api-oauth-client

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you already verified your domain and still getting this error, try to do this:

Go to your "Google Console" > "OAuth Consent Screen" and under "Publishing status" click "Back to testing"

Now you are back in the test mode, click "publish" again
You may see some new demands to publish it, which were unknown before. You could follow these demands now.

After that, you will see "The Trust and Safety team has received your form." message.

Comment: The problem is that the authorized domain is `integromat.com` which I (obviously) do not own and therefore cannot verify.

Comment: Stack Overlfow question about the `integromat.com` domain verification problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73183563/integromat-make-google-verification-for-gmail-api-oauth-client